beamer/allowframebreaks: insert a break before each item
In the beamer class with [allowframebreaks], I would like to force a frame break before every item of a list, without manually inserting \framebreak. I have found a way to insert a frame break at the start of a list with \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\framebreak}: Is there a similar command to insert a break before every item in the list?


\begin{filecontents}{input-text}
\lipsum[10]

An enumerate environment starts below this text.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,table,t,notheorems]{beamer}
\geometry{paperwidth=160mm,paperheight=96mm}% aspectratio=169: 160mm x 90mm

\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\framebreak}% works
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate items}{\framebreak}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Test}{}
\input{input-text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


framebreaks are evil, use overlays instead:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{input-text}
\lipsum[10]

An enumerate environment starts below this text.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,table,t,notheorems,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

{
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<only@+>}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\onslide<.->}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\only<2->{\vskip-3.9cm}% <- adjust to match the height of the text paragraph
\onslide<+>
\input{input-text}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}


Personally, I would add the proper beamer code to your input files and then render them harmless with \usepackage{beamerarticle} in other classes:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{input-text}
\begin{onlyenv}<+>
\lipsum[10]

An enumerate environment starts below this text.
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{enumerate}[<only@+>]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[t,notheorems,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\input{input-text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



@PatrickT " If I could combine <only@+> with \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\framebreak}" framebreaks and overlays are different concepts and should not be mixed.

@PatrickT Adding overlays between items is a piece of cake: \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<only@+>}

The overlay specification only applies to the items (and other overlay-aware elements). That's why the normal text is shown on all overlays.

I hadn't noticed that you had edited your first solution to remove the inserted code (a \begin{foo} and \end{foo} you had there initially). This solution answers my question, so I've accepted it, thanks! Your second solution, while excellent, would cause me to edit hundreds of files and having to check that they don't "break" outside of beamer, so I'm reluctant to use it. Thanks again Sam!

I asked a follow-up question about how to replace \only<2->{\vskip-3.9cm} with a more general command that does not require manually figuring out the height offset for each frame. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719810

@PatrickT The more general and un-hacky solution is use the appropriate beamer environments. beameraticle will render them harmless in other classes.

@PatrickT The solution here is to use beamerarticle and to make proper use of Beamer. Are you really turning hundreds of documents into presentations? You're essentially asking for a solution to a complex problem which already has a solution, with the restriction that an acceptable answer not involve editing the relevant code.

I have not used beamerarticle before. I'm reluctant to editing LaTeX code that works, since my main use of these is with the article class for handouts and notes, rather than to create presentations. I used to manually copy-paste the code and create frames, but that is time consuming. Now I use allowframebreaks, but the slides are very basic: by adding overlay I could have one item per slide rather than several, which would be more convenient to present one question at a time. Naturally if it's impossible, I will stick with allowframebreaks and basic slides. It's not that bad!

I have about 1000 files with questions and solutions. I can manually create nice beamer presentations by copy-pasting and correctly setting frame breaks. I've done that for about 100 of these. I was looking for an improvement on my workflow, so that I can have another 900 without any extra work! :-)

Just a follow-up for the record. I ended up doing the following: It does not allow me to break the frame at every \item, but it does otherwise allow me to create beamer frames without editing the text content.

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719427/
% I cannot edit the text inside the filecontents environment
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{input-text}
\lipsum[5]

An enumerate environment starts below this text.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[aspectratio=169,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{amsthm}% disable default theorem environments with the notheorems option to beamer class
\newtheoremstyle{solution}% not sure how many of these work
  {0pt}           %       Space above, empty = 'usual value'
  {0pt}           %       Space below
  {}              %       Body font
  {0pt}           %       Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}     %       Thm head font
  {\ }            %       Punctuation after thm head
  { }             %       Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}              %       Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{solution}
\newtheorem{solution}{}% define a simple solution environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=Navy,bg=gray!10}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%
  \vspace{-2ex}%
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{solution begin}{%
  {%
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}% disable overlays
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{solution end}{%
  {%
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}% restore overlays
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertcontinuationcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,t]{Test Frames}{}
This text is added here to check that the list begins at the correct vertical position.
\input{input-text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

